# Fluentd td-agent.log file size keep on increasing

Tags: fluentd

The log file (C:\opt\td-agent\td-agent.log) is increasing continuously, how to put a limit ??

There is some configuration like file rotate and there is a command however we have a fluentd running as windows service, so if there is any configuration could you please suggest either in .conf file or while running the fluentd service from Powershell.

To Reproduce
Keep fluentd service running and process different messages the file size keeps increasing.

Expected behavior
The old contents in the file should be deleted after a certain limit is reached.

```
<source>
  @type sql
  host HOSTNAME
  database db_name
  adapter sqlserver
  username WindowsUser
  password WindowsPwd
  <table>
    table tbl_name
    update_column insert_timestamp
  </table>
</source>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Comment: Change log level to "error" to emit less logs if warnings etc are not needed.

Comment: @Riz And where I should put that setting?

Comment: You can put <system>log_level error</system> above <source> in the same file. It should work. In linux you find it in /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf where normally you can find these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that everything mentioned in this answer will only be effective after these versions`td-agent 4.1.1 fluentd 1.12.3`. In you `td-agent.conf` file at the top add a log segment nested inside a system segment `<system><log></log></system>`. Inside those curly braces you can specify a couple options, found [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/system-config#format), in your case you would want to specify `rotate_size ###` replacing the hashtag with the size of the log file you want. You can also specify age and format.